# How to start slideshow in PowerPoint using com32

Tags: com, powerpoint

I am trying to control my PowerPoint presentation using python via com.
There is an article on how to do this [here](https://medium.com/@chasekidder/controlling-powerpoint-w-python-52f6f6bf3f2d) and it suggest I do the following:

```
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
objCOM = app.Presentations.Open(FileName="path_to_file", WithWindow=1)
objCOM.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
```

If I do this, I get the error

```
 (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, 'Microsoft PowerPoint', 'Presentation.SlideShowWindow : Invalid request.  There is currently no slide show view for this presentation.', '', 0, -2147188160), None)
```

On the last line. It seems, that `Open` does not start the slide show.

I have been looking through the documentation of the PowerPoint object model [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint), but was unable to find a way to start the slide show of a presentation.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: This code works fine for me (with a good file with double slashes like `c:\\path1\\path2\\my.pptx`). This is probably specific to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Call `SlideShowSettings.Run()` after opening the file:

```py
import win32com.client as win32
app = win32.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
objCOM = app.Presentations.Open(FileName="path_to_file", WithWindow=1)

#START THE SLIDESHOW
objCOM.SlideShowSettings.Run()

objCOM.SlideShowWindow.View.Next()
```